# Authenticate MySQL user against local Linux user account

Tags: mysql, authentication, multiple-users

Is there a way to authenticate a remote MySQL/MariaDB user against the local Linux user account by the same username? I am thinking maybe there is a plugin that validates the user using /etc/passwd?

Hypothetical example:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'remotehost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_linux;
```

Use case: Lets say I change the password for a Linux user account. I would like to avoid having to update the password for the MySQL user as well, but having it being the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to refer to [authentication plugins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/authentication-plugins.html) in particular [PAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pam-pluggable-authentication.html).   It looks like that is an Enterprise feature.  You might be able to use the open source versions from [Percona](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/management/pam_plugin.html) or [MariaDB PAM](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-pam/).

```
INSTALL SONAME 'auth_pam';
CREATE USER username@hostname IDENTIFIED VIA pam;
```

Comment: Note [MariaDB PAM](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-pam/) is however free. Take note on the required client side plugins with PAM.

Comment: @danblack Thanks.  I updated the answer with the MariaDB link you provided.

Comment: This seemed to have worked flawlessly! Thank you for providing a solution. `INSTALL SONAME 'auth_pam'; CREATE USER username@hostname IDENTIFIED VIA pam;`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the password complexity by using the [unix_socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/) authentication.

```
CREATE USER username@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;
```

This allows the unix user matching username to authenticate but no other user can authenticate as `username`.

MySQL has the [same](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) with a different syntax:

```
CREATE USER username@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
```